# Join operation not working mongo c# driver linq

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

Hi am working on mongo c# driver v2.2.3 in this they have introduced join operation ($lookup). when I try to perform join operation I am getting joint document collection count as zero . I have followed this link http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/crud/linq/  and my code is

```
    var query = from c in collection1.AsQueryable<Class>()
        join m in collection2.AsQueryable<ClassTwo>() on 
 c.ClassTwoId equals m.Id into j select new { c,j }; 
     var r = await query.ToListAsync();
```

and my class is..

```
 public class Class
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string SomeText{ get; set; }
        public ObjectId ClassTwoId { get; set; }
        public ObjectId ClassThrId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnore]
        public ClassTwo ClassTwoDeatils { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know where I did mistake... any idea ?

Comment: one way to check that is to use mongo profiler option and see generated query on mongod instance, follow Mongo Analyze Performance of Database Operations, and sett proofing level - 2. This could have insight about query. btw - is the latest mongo driver?

Comment: Yeah, I download it from Nuget Package manager

Comment: In mongo shell $lookup function is working fine ,but I am not able to replicate the same result in c# driver

Comment: I have no problem running LINQ $lookup with driver v2.2.3. Could you post your ClassTwo definition, and perhaps a document from collection1 and collection 2 as well ?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, it happens when we link (objectId) _id fields both the side, its works when you link up some other datatype likes strings, it could be bug in the driver which is not accepting objectId

Comment: A ticket was filed for this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1627

Comment: sounds good.. then we have to wait for next release....

Comment: Not working in any of the driver version.. In latest stable i am getting error : The GroupJoin query operator is not supported. Banging my head on wall :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog mentions that there is a bug in the C# driver v2.2.3, and that v2.2.4 is needed in order to use the $lookup function with the driver. It might be worth upgrading to 2.2.4 to see if that fixes your issue.

https://www.axonize.com/blog/joining-collections-mongodb-using-c-driver-linq/